# How to order data column by number in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to MVC and I want to order my result data by number

1-

2-

3-

....

In Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
var all = from emp in db.Details select emp;
return View( all);
}
```

and in my View

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th class="th">Id</th>
        <th class="th">Name</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Id)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I want to my result in view page is order by number 
1-
2-
3-
.....
Thanks

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sort with the `orderby` keyword.  For example:

```
var all = from emp in db.Details orderby emp.SomeField select emp;
```

Just use whatever field on the `emp` object has the value by which you want to sort.

---

**Edit:** Based on comments below, it sounds like instead you just want to display an incrementing integer (similar to an `ol`, but in a `table`).  That sounds more like a responsibility for the view itself, perhaps something like this with a simple `for` loop:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@i</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model[i].Id)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model[i].Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model[i].Id })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

You may need to change your model's type from `IEnumerable<T>` to `IList<T>` in order to index it.  Possibly also calling `.ToList()` on the model in the controller before sending it to the view.

(Be careful when doing that on enumerations, since it can cause unnecessary materialization of an entire collection when only part of one is needed.  But in this case the entire collection is materialized by the view engine anyway so it shouldn't make a significant difference.)

Comment: I don't want to order it by field
I want to to it by automatic generate number

Comment: @KarimMohamed: Then how do you want to order it?  You need some *value* by which to sort if you want to sort something.

Comment: OK,
If I search on my data the result will be 
1-....
5-
9-
this I don't need it 
I need after search it order by automatic such as 
<ol>
<li>
my result
</li>
</ol>
in html
I need like that in mvc

Comment: @KarimMohamed: So you just need an incrementing number in the HTML?  Like an `ol` would produce, but in a table instead?

Comment: @KarimMohamed: I've updated the answer.  If the `for` loop in the answer doesn't work for your needs, you can probably just declare a variable outside the loop and increment it manually in the loop, accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: I do all you do then I have this error
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
Line 193:        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)

Comment: @KarimMohamed: Is there any more information about the error?  I don't see anything wrong with that line of code.

Comment: Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Comment: Parser Error Message: Unexpected "for" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "for" with "@".

Comment: the error is here 

Line 193:        @for (int i=0; i < Model.Count(); i++)

Comment: @KarimMohamed: Are you already in a server-side code block from a previous line?

Comment: @KarimMohamed you can do it in easier way and you can use the index everywhere, you can check my answer.

Comment: thank You
my error was in foreach,
I remove it then it run exactly I wont
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreach to a for and use the iterator

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th> class="th">number</th>
            <th class="th">Id</th>
            <th class="th">Name</th>
            <th>Some other column so your table renders correctly</th>
        </tr>

        @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@i.ToString()<!-- i put the number here but whateves. --></td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model[i].Id)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model[i].Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<TestClass> a = new List<TestClass>();

    TestClass t1 = new TestClass();
    t1.Test1 = "a";
    t1.Test2 = "b";
    t1.Test3 = "c";
    t1.Test4 = "d";

    TestClass t2 = new TestClass();
    t2.Test1 = "a2";
    t2.Test2 = "b3";
    t2.Test3 = "c4";
    t2.Test4 = "d5";

    a.Add(t1);
    a.Add(t2);

    var result = (from collRow in a
                 select collRow).Select((d, i) => new 
                 {
                     Data = d,

                     Index = i
                 });

    foreach(var p in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Index);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here is a way to make it in the linq, you should use Select which passes you an index. Here an msdn article about it with more examples : [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx)

So in the code should like something like this.

```
  //probably it will be needed to be add .AsEnumerable() before the Select
 var all = (from emp in db.Details select emp).Select((d, i) => new
            {
                 Data = d,
                 // if you want the index to start from 1, Index=i+1
                 Index = i
            });
```

After that in your view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Index)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Data.ID)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Data.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Data.ID })</td>
    </tr>
}
```